# Picture-word puzzle

Tags: word, visual, rebus

Couldn't figure this one out for the life of me.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you please provide attribution for your puzzle, since it appears it was not self-created?

Comment: baseball + apple + cat + rake + er
re - skate - brick - burger

Comment: this was posted by my RA (I live in a college dorm) earlier this week, he said he'll give the answer in a week but it's right there in the hall and it's been bugging me like hell

Comment: @Jordan.J.D please take a closer look. The first patch has two lines of images. The second patch says there are two words and gives the number of letters in each. With a hint.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D: Also, the brick and the burger are **+**. (And the third image *might* be a kitten.) And the first image on the second line is specifically an *ice* skate.  And the final image might be some other kinf of sandwich; e.g., a sub.

Comment: More context: this is not actually from a dorm room, this is a contest to win an expensive piece of glass: https://www.instagram.com/p/BokAlMdnhf5/ there is a video there with better resolution

Comment: the ice skate also has "bower" written on it

Comment: and lastly, the contest host also mentioned that is has to do with ayahuasca

Comment: The ice skate might be for figure skating, so figure - re = figu?

Comment: Wait a sec: should we not be working on this puzzle if it’s for a currently active contest? I might have to put this on hold it so.

Comment: The deadline has been and gone twice. Please re-open, the company is just milking the unexpected viral appeal by not revealing an answer.